# integration substitution what am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration

integrate $\frac{x^3}{(4+x^2)}$

Let $u = 4+x^2$ so $\frac{du}{2}=xdx$

Then I need to integrate $\frac{(u-4)}{u}$ which comes out as $u-4\ln u$

converting back to $x$, $4+x^2-4 \ln(4+x^2)+C$

But I should never get a constant 4 when integrating. Do I just absorb it into the $C$? I think I must have made an error.

Comment: Yes, you can absorb it into the C, and I think you have a missing factor of 1/2 from the du.

Answer (score 0):

x^3/(4+x^2)=x-(4x/(4+x^2)), now you have two factors to integrate integrateing x you have x^2/2 and for the second part you have -2ln(4+x^2) so the answer is (x^2/2)-2ln(4+x^2)+C.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int\frac{x^{3}}{4+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x =
  \begin{cases}
    4+x^2=u       \\
    \implies2x\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}u \\
  \end{cases}\bigg\}=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{u-4}{u}\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{2}u-2\ln(u)+C=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+4)-2\ln(x^2+4)+C=\frac{1}{2}x^2-2\ln(x^2+4)+C$$